# Screen resolution changed on Debian and it is impossible to get it back

Tags: graphics, resolution

Today, after shutting down my laptop from Windows, I turned on my computer and realized GRUB was zoomed-in, and also Plymouth start screen. SDDM and KDE where zoomed in too, and even TTYs. After checking my screen resolution it changed from 1600x1200 to 1024x768. KDE doesn't show any higher resolutions in system settings. On Windows I was able to set the resolution to 1600x1200 and now it works fine.

I looked at many answers and most of them tells to update the graphic drivers, but I didn't update anything (so they should work the same) and I have an Intel Integrated, not a NVIDIA.
Some of them also tells to create a new screen with `xrandr`, but since it was working fine before I don't want a complicated solution and I hope to find an easier one. I also don't think this solution would work for GRUB since to my knowledge GRUB doesn't use X.org on "console" mode.

###### `neofetch`

```
       _,met$$$$$gg.          username@PC-username
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       ----------------
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) x86_64
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: ESPRIMO P420
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 5.10.0-22-amd64
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 12 mins
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 3768 (dpkg), 16 (flatpak), 22 (snap)
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: zsh 5.8
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 1024x768
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         DE: Plasma 5.20.5
 `$$b      "-.__              WM: KWin
  `Y$$                        Theme: Breeze Dark [Plasma], Adwaita-dark [GTK2/3]
   `Y$$.                      Icons: breeze-dark [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3]
     `$$b.                    Terminal: alacritty
       `Y$$b.                 Terminal Font: "MesloLGS NF"
          `"Y$b._             CPU: Intel i5-4570 (4) @ 3.600GHz
              `"""            GPU: Intel HD Graphics
                              Memory: 2171MiB / 15901MiB
```

###### `xrandr --verbose`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (0x44) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x41
    Timestamp:  223210
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter:
    link-status: Good
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 61
        supported: 61
    non-desktop: 0
        range: (0, 1)
  1024x768 (0x44) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync *current
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x45) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x46) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  848x480 (0x47) 33.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   848 start  864 end  976 total 1088 skew    0 clock  31.02KHz
        v: height  480 start  486 end  494 total  517           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x48) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
HDMI-1 disconnected (my screen is plugged on VGA)
```

> **EDIT:** It fixed itself after multiple reboots, but if anyone know why this happened please tell me.

> **EDIT 2:** Happened again. I'm still waiting for a solution.